# Is it possible to define two variables with the same name in two different segments?

Tags: variables, assembly, emu8086, memory-segmentation

I want to define two variables in two different segments with the same name and different values in Assembly language.
I use Emu8086 and I tried it as below but it didn't work:

```
DATASG1 SEGMENT 'DATA'
    DATA1 DB 10H
    DATASG1 ENDS
DATASG2 SEGMENT 'DATA'
    DATA1 DB 10H
    DATASG2 ENS
DATASG SEGMENT 'CODE'
MAIN PROC NEAR
    MOV AX, DATASG1
    MOV DS, AX
    MOV AL, DATA1
    MAIN ENDP
    DATASG ENDS
    END MAIN
```

**My questions are:**

> - Is it possible?
> - If yes, how?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I just want to know how c/c++ can recognize two different variables with a same name which are defined in different functions. I heared from somewhere that c/c++ convert their code to assembly and then to machine.

Comment: @Lopag: The way C and C++ do this is utterly different. Logically speaking, local variables are `equ` offsets in asm, but most compilers omit the stack offsets directly.

Comment: By default the symbols in MASM can only be seen in the module (object) they are defined. If you want a symbol to be available in other modules (objects) you must declare it as `PUBLIC`. Then they can be referenced in other objects using the EXTERN directive. This is how it is done when a compiler (like C) is told to generate assembly code.

Comment: @Lopag automatic variables do not correspond to symbols and for local static variables, the compiler simply chooses different symbol names for the two variables.  For example, variable `foo` in one function may become `L123` and `foo` in the other may become `L456`.  The symbol names may not have a correlation to the variable names.

Comment: In MASM/EMU8086 inside the same module (object) you can't have the same symbol name in two different segments. In EMU8086 you can only have one module.